# Remove class of another element with jQuery when clicking element

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass, toggleclass

I am having an issue with my code.

Currently the `.active` class is being applied when I click on divs that read ebook image 1, ebook image 2, ebook image 3, as intended.

What I would like to do is to remove the `.active` class when I click the div itself, which it is not currently doing.

https://fiddle.jshell.net/aerandur/v20hmy3b/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.one').on('click', function() {
    $('.one').removeClass('active');
    $id = "#" + $(this).addClass('active').attr('data-id');
    $('.two:not(' + $id + ')').hide();
    $($id).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/* .container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.frame {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
 */
.one {
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 25px 10px;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.two {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="whatever-you-wanna-name top-product-list-ebbok">
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="c-3 one" data-id="p1">ebook image 1</div>
    <div class="c-3 one" data-id="p2">ebook image 2</div>
    <div class="c-3 one" data-id="p3">ebook image 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="whatever-you-wanna-name top-product-list-description">
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="two" id="p1">ebook for content image 1</div>
    <div class="two" id="p2">ebook for content image 2</div>
    <div class="two" id="p3">ebook for content image 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean remove `.active` from `.one` when they click `.two`?

Comment: You've added the `toggleClass` tag here. Might want to [look into how that works](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest option, as far as I can tell. Refine the selector by using `.not(this)`, and then toggle the class on the element itself.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.one').on('click', function() {
    $('.one').not(this).removeClass('active');
    $id = "#" + $(this).toggleClass('active').attr('data-id');
    $('.two:not(' + $id + ')').hide();
    $($id).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

https://fiddle.jshell.net/v20hmy3b/10/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution, someone might be able to simplify the solution but it does work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.one').on('click', function() {
    
    if(!$(this).hasClass("active")){
      $('.one').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');      
    }
    else{
      $('.one').removeClass('active');
      }
    
    $id = "#" + $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('.two:not(' + $id + ')').hide();
    $($id).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
/* .container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.frame {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
 */
.one {
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 25px 10px;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.two {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="whatever-you-wanna-name top-product-list-ebbok">
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="c-3 one" data-id="p1">ebook image 1</div>
    <div class="c-3 one" data-id="p2">ebook image 2</div>
    <div class="c-3 one" data-id="p3">ebook image 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="whatever-you-wanna-name top-product-list-description">
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="two" id="p1">ebook for content image 1</div>
    <div class="two" id="p2">ebook for content image 2</div>
    <div class="two" id="p3">ebook for content image 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like that ?
https://fiddle.jshell.net/zzwctuq9/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.one').on('click', function() 
  {
   
    if (  $( this ).hasClass('active'))
    {
     $( this ).removeClass('active');
    }
    else
    {
    $( this ).addClass('active');
    }

    $id = "#" + $(this).attr('data-id');
    $($id).slideToggle();
  });  
});
```

```css
/* .container {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.frame {
  max-width: 940px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
 */
.one {
  top: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 25px 10px;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 200px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.two {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  display: none;
}

.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="whatever-you-wanna-name top-product-list-ebbok">
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="c-3 one" data-id="p1">ebook image 1</div>
    <div class="c-3 one" data-id="p2">ebook image 2</div>
    <div class="c-3 one" data-id="p3">ebook image 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="whatever-you-wanna-name top-product-list-description">
  <div class="frame">
    <div class="two" id="p1">ebook for content image 1</div>
    <div class="two" id="p2">ebook for content image 2</div>
    <div class="two" id="p3">ebook for content image 3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.one').on('click', function() {
    if(!$(this).hasClass('active')){
       $('.one').removeClass('active');
    }    
    $id = "#" + $(this).toggleClass('active').attr('data-id');
    $('.two:not(' + $id + ')').hide();
    $($id).slideToggle();
  });
});
```